# Nested control structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

Is there any way to create nested control structure?
For example I tried this. But I got error.

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String  

bmiTell bmi  = if bmi <= 18.5  then if bmi==16.0 then "asdasdasdsad"
           else if bmi <= 25.0 then "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet  you're ugly!"  
           else if bmi <= 30.0 then "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
           else    "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

Comment: I think you need to add some curly braces to get that to work.

Comment: @pubby braces, while syntactically legal, are not required for or even very commonly seen in Haskell if-then-else statements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `if` expression is parsed as

```
if bmi <= 18.5   -- no else!
  then if bmi==16.0
         then "asdasdasdsad"
         else if bmi <= 25.0
                then "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet  you're ugly!"  
                else if bmi <= 30.0
                       then "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
                       else "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

Note that the first `if` has a `then` branch but no `else` branch.

**In Haskell, every `if` expression must have a `then` branch *and* an `else` branch. So that's your problem.**

I second bchurchill's suggestion of using guards rather than nested `if` expressions.

Comment: This is also gives error. The same:Syntax error in expression (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad layout)

Comment: @molten What do you want to happen if `bmi` is less than 18.5 but not equal to 16.0? That is basically the missing `else` branch.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, you just need to indent things properly.  ghc probably doesn't like being told it's fat either.  In either case, the indenting determines what branches correspond to what statements, and I might have messed up the order a bit:

```
bmiTell bmi  = if bmi <= 18.5  
               then if bmi==16.0 
                    then "asdasdasdsad"
                    else if bmi <= 25.0 
                         then "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet  you're ugly!"  
                         else if bmi <= 30.0 
                              then "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
                              else    "You're a whale, congratulations!"  
               else "foobar"
```

The better way to do this is with a guarded conditional, e.g.

```
bmiTell bmi
  | bmi < 18.5 = "foo"
  | bmi < 25.0 = "bar"
  | bmi < 30.0 = "buzz"
```

Comment: It gives this error:Syntax error in expression (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad layout). By the way I'm using hugs. How can I handle this?

Comment: But the function with guards doesn't include nested structure.

Comment: @molten The function with guards had a mistake in it. Fixed now.

Comment: Indentation of `if`-`then`-`else` is irrelevant as far as the compiler is concerned (although of course it can make it more understandable for humans).